# How to display list item in a workflow approval task form for the list item?

Tags: sharepoint

We are customizing workflow approval form to display the associated list item fields. This will help the approver to verify the list item, he is approving.

Comment: Are you building a workflow in Visual Studio or SharePoint Designer? Are you building forms as aspx pages or InfoPath forms?

Comment: We are building the workflow using SharePoint designer and using aspx pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approval form will have to be one of 2 flavors.. this is assuming that you are using Windows Workflow Foundation...

1. InfoPath workflow form and Windows Workflow Foundation - These are the forms that are normally used for MOSS (not WSS) workflows.  In order to provide list data you will need to send the list information up to the task form using the ItemMetadata.xml and SPWorflowTaskProperties.ExtendedProperties[].  If you didn't want to send that info you can try to use VSTA in the form and retrieve said information programmatically into InfoPath.
2. ASPX Form - Not too many people have created custom task forms (your approval form is really a task form).  This form needs to be deployed to the _Layouts directory and is quite difficult to create.  I recommend searching Robert Shelton's blog as he has a great example of how to create a SharePoint aspx task form.

Ulysses